# $corodova.geolocation not fetching longitude and latitude of current location in IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, ionic-framework

i have use $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition in ionic app. its working properly in android and web and fetch location properly. but in xcode simulator its not working and can not able to fetch latitude an longitude. and can not able to fetch longitude and latitude.

```
var posOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 20000,
  maximumAge: 0
};


$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {

  $scope.Lat  = position.coords.latitude;
  $scope.Long = position.coords.longitude;

  console.log('lat:', $scope.Lat);
  console.log('long:', $scope.Long);    
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

i have put this code in `.run` function `app.js` file.

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("corodova.geolocation works well");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In iPhone simulator you can simulate location.

You need to go Debug -> Location -> Custom Location

[image: location]

and you can add custom lat long in dialog box and press OK.

[image]

You can also simulate location from Xcode.

For that you need to run an application and above the log area you will see navigation button like below image and select city from list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simulator cant detect location automatically.

simulate location ios simulator

Launch the iOS Simulator. Then, open the iOS Simulator's Debug menu and select Location .